# How to traverse JSON data using ng-repeat

Tags: json, angularjs-ng-repeat

How to traverse follow JSON data in table

Object { itemCode=1,  itemDesc="Banana",  amount=23,}

Answer (score 0):

try to write a filter in the angular like follow

```
app.filter('reverse', function() {
  return function(items) {
    return items.slice().reverse();
  };
});
```

or

```
app.filter('reverse', function() {
  return function(items) {
    return items.reverse();
  };
});
```

and then in the ng-repeat use that filter like follow:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | reverse">{{item}}</div>
```

Comment: I am getting json response, how

Comment: i am getting json response from spring MVC controller, and want to print in table in tabular form.?

Comment: use table html tag and inside ng-repeat put tr and td tags ... do you mean that

Comment: that is fine, but from spring controller , i am getting data that is array of json object, how to store that array into normal json array..

Comment: see these two links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20881213/converting-json-object-into-javascript-array .... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22687771/how-to-convert-jsonobjects-to-jsonarray