# Android: converting JSONObject to JSONArray returns null

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

My code:

```
JSONObject data = {"result":{"a":[{"artist":"Aney","number:"1"},{"artist":"Aney","number:"2"}],"b":[{"artist":"Boney","number:"3"},{"artist":"Boney","number:"4"}], ....
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(data.toString());
JSONArray tasks = obj.optJSONArray("result");
```

But `tasks` returns `null`.

I tried the below code but it did not work:

```
JSONObject data = {"result":{"a":[{"artist":"Money",...
JSONArray tasks = data.optJSONArray("result");
```

Update :

My main code is :

```
// get data from main url and reutnr array
JSONArray tasks = data.optJSONArray("result");
if(alert){
    // get data from another url and return object
    JSONObject data = {"result":{"a":[{"artist":"Money",...
    tasks = data.optJSONArray("result");
}

// now i use tasks in my code
if(tasks.length() > 0){
    ....
}
```

Comment: `data.result` is a JSON object, not an array

Comment: `data = {"result": { ... }}`

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22687771/how-to-convert-jsonobjects-to-jsonarray) might be useful.

Comment: @LAD thank you. but my json code have very key and value. this is take time

Comment: @geekley i want convert to array

Comment: then you have to parse it as an object and then go through each property adding to an array so that you get the structure you want

Comment: you should give an example with the value you would epect when you call `tasks = data.optJSONArray("result")`. Also, what is the structure of `"result"`? Does it have "a", "b", and so on? Or is it a single "a" field with the array you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see `"key": { ... }`, that means `key` is a `JSONObject`.

When you see `"key": [ ... ]`, that means `key` is a `JSONArray`.

In your case, `"result"` is a `JSONObject`, so write this instead:

```
JSONObject tasks = obj.optJSONObject("result");
```

Comment: @salarimameri well, the `results` object **isn't** an array, so you're going to have to clarify what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

The JSONArray (a, b) is inside the object 'result' inside of the root object so you have to navigate the hyerarchy to get it:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(data.toString());
JSONObject result = obj.getJSONObject("result");
JSONArray tasksA = result.optJSONArray("a");
JSONArray tasksB = result.optJSONArray("b");
```

Note that each 'a' and 'b' is a different JSONArray to be retrieved.