# How to convert list of JSON objects to JsonArray and then iterate on it?

Tags: java, json, deserialization, geojson, json-deserialization

I'm trying to convert a string (every `JSON` object is separated by commas, but first `JSON` object is the description of this collection) with `JSON` objects to `JsonArray` and then I'm trying to iterate on some subelement of each `JsonElement`, but every single attempt ends up with an error.

String example:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","metadata":{"generated":1554314439000,"url":"https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&eventtype=earthquake","title":"USGS Earthquakes","status":200,"api":"1.7.0","count":8970},"features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"mag":2.2,"place":"84km SSE of Old Iliamna, Alaska","time":1554313967537,"updated":1554314345998,"tz":-540,"url":"https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/ak0194a3ew0w","detail":"https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=ak0194a3ew0w&format=geojson","felt":null,"cdi":null,"mmi":null,"alert":null,"status":"automatic","tsunami":0,"sig":74,"net":"ak","code":"0194a3ew0w","ids":",ak0194a3ew0w,","sources":",ak,","types":",geoserve,origin,","nst":null,"dmin":null,"rms":0.74,"gap":null,"magType":"ml","type":"earthquake","title":"M 2.2 - 84km SSE of Old Iliamna, Alaska"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-154.542,59.0119,127.6]},"id":"ak0194a3ew0w"},

{"type":"Feature","properties":{"mag":1.1,"place":"107km W of Cantwell, Alaska","time":1554313769466,"updated":1554313953376,"tz":-540,"url":"https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/ak0194a3e7ki","detail":"https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=ak0194a3e7ki&format=geojson","felt":null,"cdi":null,"mmi":null,"alert":null,"status":"automatic","tsunami":0,"sig":19,"net":"ak","code":"0194a3e7ki","ids":",ak0194a3e7ki,","sources":",ak,","types":",geoserve,origin,","nst":null,"dmin":null,"rms":0.63,"gap":null,"magType":"ml","type":"earthquake","title":"M 1.1 - 107km W of Cantwell, Alaska"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-151.0662,63.2378,7.8]},"id":"ak0194a3e7ki"},
```

I've tried:

```
JsonArray jsonObject = new JsonParser()
                    .parse(result)
                    .getAsJsonArray();
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
for (JsonElement jsonElement : jsonObject) {
    names.add(jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("properties").getAsString());
```

Comment: Can you post the stackTrace ?

Comment: From this part of code I receive:
String result = IOUtils.toString(in, "UTF-8");

            JsonArray jsonObject = new JsonParser()
                    .parse(result)
                    .getAsJsonArray();

Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This is not a JSON Array.

Comment: Your string example is not a proper `JSON Object`.
Refer to this probably you will find an answer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22687771/how-to-convert-jsonobjects-to-jsonarray]

Comment: Read the file into a `String`, split it on the delimiter, parse each piece into a `JsonObject`, and add parsed object to a preexisting `JsonArray`.

Comment: I've used this url to retrieve JSON object that I'm using in this solution:
https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&eventtype=earthquake

Comment: It should be validated in this url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[earthquake.usgs.gov](https://earthquake.usgs.gov/) API returns payload in [`GeoJSON`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946) format. There is [`geogson`](https://github.com/filosganga/geogson) library which implements all needed adapters. You need to only add dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.github.filosganga</groupId>
   <artifactId>geogson-core</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.21</version>
</dependency>
```

and below you can find simple example how to use it:

```
import com.github.filosganga.geogson.gson.GeometryAdapterFactory;
import com.github.filosganga.geogson.model.FeatureCollection;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class GsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL("https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&eventtype=earthquake");
        URLConnection yc = url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapterFactory(new GeometryAdapterFactory())
                .create();

        FeatureCollection collection = gson.fromJson(in, FeatureCollection.class);
        collection.features().forEach(f -> {
            System.out.println(f.properties());
        });
    }
}
```

Above app prints:

```
null, cdi=null, url="https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us1000jimv", ids=",us1000jimv,", time=1552230050190, detail="https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us1000jimv&format=geojson", updated=1553025676040, status="reviewed"}
{dmin=0.01354, code="73150236", sources=",nc,", tz=-480, mmi=null, type="earthquake", title="M 0.3 - 8km WNW of Cobb, CA", magType="md", nst=10, sig=2, tsunami=0, mag=0.32, alert=null, gap=159, rms=0.02, place="8km WNW of Cobb, CA", net="nc", types=",geoserve,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,scitech-link,", felt=null, cdi=null, url="https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/nc73150236", ids=",nc73150236,", time=1552229803430, detail="https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=nc73150236&format=geojson", updated=1552436044263, status="reviewed"}
{dmin=0.0134, code="73150231", sources=",nc,", tz=-480, mmi=null, type="earthquake", title="M 0.6 - 8km WNW of Cobb, CA", magType="md", nst=9, sig=5, tsunami=0, mag=0.57, alert=null, gap=152, rms=0.01, place="8km WNW of Cobb, CA", net="nc", types=",geoserve,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,scitech-link,", felt=null, cdi=null, url="https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/nc73150231", ids=",nc73150231,", time=1552229731210, detail="https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=nc73150231&format=geojson", updated=1552235523281, status="automatic"}
....
```

Comment: Hi Michał, thank you very much for the reply. but I've got an error in f.properties():

Error:(26, 39) java: cannot access com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap
  class file for com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap not found

Comment: @b36, you need to include [Guava: Google Core Libraries For Java](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava)

Comment: Ok, works with such a dependency:
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>10.0.1-v201203051515</version>
</dependency>

Comment: @b36, I'm glad to hear that. For more info how `SO` works take a look on [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really aprreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are in a JavaEE project you are good to go, but if you are in a JavaSE project you need to add these dependencies.

For example, using maven:

```xml
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.25.1</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And here it is the code:

- First line, calling your url.
- Second line, processing response as json.

```
public void loadData() {
        Response response = ClientBuilder.newClient().target("https://earthquake.usgs.gov")
                .path("/fdsnws/event/1/query")
                .queryParam("format", "geojson")
                .queryParam("eventtype", "earthquake")
                .request()
                .get();

        Json.createReader((InputStream) response.getEntity())
                .readObject().getJsonArray("features")
                .stream()
                .map(JsonValue::asJsonObject)
                .map(jsonObject -> jsonObject.getJsonObject("properties"))
                .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

As you can see this code prints on screen every single JsonObject called "properties" inside an array called "features".

**Important:** Be aware that string example you gave in your question is not a valid JSON. Use the one returned by url.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your exhausting reply. Could you please advice how to resolve ClientBuilder Cannot resolve symbol 'ClientBuilder') and response.getEntity() ("Cannot resolve method 'getEntity()") within these libraries? I have added deps in pom.xml and added jar files according to provided realeses. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Ok, it has been resolved, but when I try to run it there is an error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClientBuilder
 at javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newBuilder(ClientBuilder.java:110)
 at javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newClient(ClientBuilder.java:121)
 at retrieveEarthquakeData.postJSON(retrieveEarthquakeData.java:24)
 at showEarthquakes.main(showEarthquakes.java:3)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ...

Comment: @b36 I have just updated my answer with a different dependency, try it out and see if solves that error. In my test is working fine. Cheers!

Comment: Hi, still the same error occuring. I've tried to resolve, but no effect.