# Put a JSONObject into JSONArray

Tags: java, android

I have a **JSONObject** I want to convert this into an array.

```
{
    "confirmationTypes": [
        {
            "confirmationTypeCode": "A"
        },
        {
            "confirmationTypeCode": "B"
        }
    ]
}
```

array = [confirmationTypes]

Example:

```
[
    {
     "confirmationTypes": [
        {
            "confirmationTypeCode": "A"
        },
        {
            "confirmationTypeCode": "B"
        }
      ]
    }
]
```

How do I achieve this type of `JSONArray` format

Comment: I don't understand what you have and what you want. The 2 piece of code are the same, except that the 2nd is an array of previous object (containing an array).

Comment: use this to achieve what you want

`JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
jsonArray.put(yourJsonObject)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert JSONObjects to JSONArray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22687771/how-to-convert-jsonobjects-to-jsonarray)

Answer (score 0):

use  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode library and parse your json string like below and given objectNode you can treat like a jsonArray and iterate through it.

Since "confirmationTypes" field is having an array.So fetch the value of this array using this("confirmationTypes") key.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode objectNode = mapper.readTree(inputJson);
for(JsonNode node : objectNode.get("confirmationTypes")){
         System.out.println(node.get("confirmationTypeCode").asText());
     }
```

There are many features are there for json node you can even extract complex Json.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ArrayList to achieve this output.

```
ArrayList<JsonObject> list = new ArrayList<JsonObject>();
list.add(yourJsonObject)
```

> or as  @Anurag Shrivastava said,

```
JsonArray array = new JsonArray();
array.put(yourJsonObject);
```

Pretty Simple