# Parse json and get inner object

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I need to parse a json on android like:

```
{"header": {
        "param": "param"
    },
    "body": {
        "param": "1",
        "param2": "2",
        "param3": [
            {
                "param4": "4",
                "param5": "5"
            },
            {
                "param6": "6"
            }
        ],
        "param7": "7",
        "param12": [
            {
                "param8": "8",
                "param13": [
                    {
                        "param9": "9"
                    },
                    {
                        "param10": "10"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "param11": "11"
    }
}
```

My code is:

```
org.json.simple.JSONObject LJsonObj = (org.json.simple.JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(AString);
try {
    JSONArray LBody = (JSONArray) LJsonObj.get("body");
    result = LBody.toString();
    LStrTemp = result;
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    LJsonObj.clear();
}

return result;
```

It breaks or does not work at all at the moment:

```
JSONArray LBody = (JSONArray) LJsonObj.get ("body");
```

How can I parse the `body` tag?

Where is the error, tell me?

String, Integer, and other types are parsed without problems by this principle. And with json there are more complicated problems

Comment: Have a look at this answer, it might be related: [How to convert JSONObjects to JSONArray](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22687862/12806461)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the error logs it's hard to say exactly but I think it has to do with the fact that you are using a JSONArray when "body" is an object. Try JSONObject instead.

Comment: It was my pleasure!